# cumulative max by group in SAS or PROC SQL

Tags: sas

I want to compute a cumulative max grouped by another column.

Say I have this data:

```
data have;
input grp $ number;
datalines;
a 3
b 4
a 5
b 2
a 1
b 8
;
```

My desired output would be:

```
data want;
input grp $ cummax;
a 3
b 4
a 5
b 4
a 5
b 8
;
```

My real case will involve several grouping columns + filters, and ideally this cumulative max would be computed on several columns at the same time.

My main concern is computational efficiency as I'll be running this on tables of ten to hundred millions of rows. Proc SQL or native SAS are both welcome.

Rows might be shuffled if necessary.

**System Info**

```
proc product_status;run;
```

> ```
> For Base SAS Software ...
>    Custom version information: 9.3_M2
>    Image version information: 9.03.01M2P080112
> For SAS/STAT ...
>    Custom version information: 12.1
>    Image version information: 9.03.01M0P081512
> For SAS/GRAPH ...
>    Custom version information: 9.3_M2
> For SAS/CONNECT ...
>    Custom version information: 9.3_M2
> For SAS OLAP Server ...
>    Custom version information: 9.3_M1
> For SAS Enterprise Miner ...
>    Custom version information: 12.1
>    Image version information: 9.03.01M0P081512
> For SAS Integration Technologies ...
>    Custom version information: 9.3_M2
> For SAS/ACCESS Interface to Oracle ...
>    Custom version information: 9.3_M1
> For SAS/ACCESS Interface to PC Files ...
>    Custom version information: 9.3_M2
> ```

```
    proc setinit;run;
```

> ```
> Product expiration dates:
> ---Base SAS Software                                                                                    31JUL2018  
> ---SAS/STAT                                                                                             31JUL2018  
> ---SAS/GRAPH                                                                                            31JUL2018  
> ---SAS/CONNECT                                                                                          31JUL2018  
> ---SAS OLAP Server                                                                                      31JUL2018  
> ---SAS Enterprise Miner                                                                                 31JUL2018  
> ---MDDB Server common products                                                                          31JUL2018  
> ---SAS Integration Technologies                                                                         31JUL2018  
> ---SAS Enterprise Miner Server                                                                          31JUL2018  
> ---SAS Enterprise Miner Client                                                                          31JUL2018  
> ---Unused OLAP Slot                                                                                     31JUL2018  
> ---SAS Enterprise Guide                                                                                 31JUL2018  
> ---SAS/ACCESS Interface to Oracle                                                                       31JUL2018  
> ---SAS/ACCESS Interface to PC Files                                                                     31JUL2018  
> ---SAS Metadata Bridges for Informatica                                                                 31JUL2018  
> ---SAS Metadata Bridges for Microsoft SQL Server                                                        31JUL2018  
> ---SAS Metadata Bridge for Oracle                                                                       31JUL2018  
> ---SAS Workspace Server for Local Access                                                                31JUL2018  
> ---SAS Workspace Server for Enterprise Access                                                           31JUL2018  
> ---SAS Table Server                                                                                     31JUL2018  
> ---DataFlux Trans DB Driver                                                                             31JUL2018  
> ---SAS Framework Data Server                                                                            31JUL2018  
> ---SAS Add-in for Microsoft Excel                                                                       31JUL2018  
> ---SAS Add-in for Microsoft Outlook                                                                     31JUL2018  
> ---SAS Add-in for Microsoft PowerPoint                                                                  31JUL2018  
> ---SAS Add-in for Microsoft Word                                                                        31JUL2018
> ```

Comment: Do you have SAS ETS licensed? What have you tried, even for the simple case? You should expand your sample data to better reflect your actual situation with several grouping variables.

Comment: There are good chances that I have, but I'm not sure how to check it :). I gave short data to make my point but you're right i'll edit with an additional more complex case.

Comment: `proc setinit;run;` to see what's licensed, `proc product_status;run;` to see what's installed.

Comment: I added my system info above, I'll need a bit more time to come up with a complex example table, meanwhile solving the simple example will be a great help.

Comment: The solution below works. I wouldn't recommend SQL here unless you can do pass through and use some DBMS functions. You don't have SAS/ETS which would have allowed you to use PROC EXPAND.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `HASH` object to store the max for each variable and group combination.  This will allow you to single pass through your data set and code something that you can scale for the number of groups and variables.

This does not require a sort which can be costly on a large data set.

Test Data

```
data example;
format grp1-grp5 $1.;
array grp[5];
array val[5];
do rows=1 to 1000000;
    do i=1 to 5;
        r = ceil(ranuni(1)*5);
        grp[i] = substr("ABCDE",r,1);
    end;
    do j=1 to 5;
        val[j] = 10*rannor(1);
    end;
    output;
end;
keep grp: val:;
run;
```

Data Step to compute the cumulative max

```
data want;
set example;
array val[5];
array max[5];
if _n_ = 1 then do;
    declare hash mx();
    rc = mx.defineKey('grp1','grp2','grp3','grp4','grp5');
    rc = mx.definedata('max1','max2','max3','max4','max5');
    rc = mx.definedone();
end;

rc = mx.find();
/*No Max for this combination -- add it*/
if rc then do;
    do i=1 to 5;
        max[i] = val[i];
    end;
end;

/*Update Max Values*/
do i=1 to 5;
    if val[i] > max[i] then
        max[i] = val[i];
end;

/*Update Hash*/
rc = mx.replace();

drop rc i;
n = _n_; /*This is for testing*/
run;
```

Using that testing variable `n`, we can sort the groups keeping the original order and see if it worked.  (hint, it did).

```
proc sort data=want;
by grp: n;
run;
```

Comment: I upped the number of rows to 100,000,000 (4.5G input size).  My laptop computes the max values in 1:55.89.

Comment: I test it and it works. The code looks also very elegant. But may be I do not understand hash object and its methods very well. The thing confused me is that, if you do not find the combination keys in the mx hash, then you assign the val to max variables. But you do not really add them to the hash, the same for the next step of updating max. How these values are added in mx? It would be very helpful, if you could explain a bit further. Thanks!

Comment: The replace() method will add the values if they do not already exist.  You could add mx.add() to that block, but you don't need to.

Comment: Now I see, and it works together with find(). When the combinations are already in the hash, you take the max value from the hash, which would be the previous max and assign them to current variables by find(). Then you compare current val variables with current max which equal to the previous max. If it is bigger, you assign the new max and using replace() to update the new values in hash. Very clear and elegant, Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
proc sort data=have;
by grp;
run;

data want;
   set have;
   by grp;
   retain max;
   max=ifn(first.grp,number,max(number,max));
run;
```

Use Hash without sort

```
data want;
  if _n_=1 then do;
  declare hash h();
  h.definekey('grp');
  h.definedata('value');
  h.definedone();
  end;
  set have;
  if h.find()^=0 then do;
  h.add(key:grp,data:number);
  max=number;
  end;
  else do;
     max=max(number,value);
     h.replace(key:grp,data:number);
  end;
  drop  value number;
run;
```

Comment: I like the solution with hash, which is simple enough and preserve the original order as well

Answer (score 1):

something like the following will work.  If you want to keep the original order add a row counter and resort on that:

```
proc sort data=have; 
by grp; 
run;

data new; 
drop newnum; 
set have;            
by grp;   
retain newnum;                                                  
if first.grp then newnum = number; 
if number > newnum then newnum=number;  
else number=newnum;
run;
```

Comment: Thanks it works, I'll see if someone comes with a competitor efficiency-wise and validate then :)

Comment: may be if number > newnum then newnum=number; can be changed to else if number > newnum then newnum=number;

Comment: This solution is simple and works fine. However, it requires sorting, therefore dose not preserve the order of the original data

Answer (score 1):

I built a macro function wrapped around @DomPazz 's solution, one can choose which columns to group by, which columns to compute on and which columns to drop or keep in the end.

I think included examples are straightforward.

I joined at the bottom the short convenience macro functions that I use in `cummax`.

```
*------------------------------------------------------------;
* CUMMAX                                                     ;
* Compute a cumulative max on 1 or several variables grouped ;
* by one or several variables;                               ;
*------------------------------------------------------------;
/* EXAMPLE:
data have;
format grp1-grp2 $1.;
array grp[2];
array val[3];
do rows=1 to 20;
    do i=1 to 2;
        r = ceil(ranuni(1)*2);
        grp[i] = substr("AB",r,1);
    end;
    do j=1 to 3;
        val[j] = 10*rannor(1);
    end;
    output;
end;
keep grp: val:;
run;

%cummax(have,grp=grp1 grp2,val=val1 val2,out= want1)
%cummax(have,grp=grp1,val=val1,drop=grp2 val3,out= want2)
%cummax(have,grp=grp1,val=val1,keep= val2,out= want3)
*/

%macro cummax
(data  /* source table */
,grp=  /* variables to group on */
,val=  /* variables to compute on */
,keep= /* variables to keep additionally to grp and computed columns, don't use with drop */
,drop= /* variables to drop, don't use with keep */
,out=  /* output table */
);

/* default output */
%if not %length(&out) %then %let out = &data;

/* rework keep and drop */
%local n_val max_val;
%let n_val   = %list_length(&val);
%let max_val = %list_fix(&val,suffix=_cmax);
%if %length(&keep) %then %let keep = (keep= &keep &grp &max_val );
%if %length(&drop) %then %let drop = (drop= &drop);

/* data step */
data &out&keep&drop;
set &data;
array val[&n_val] &val;
array max[&n_val] &max_val;

if _n_ = 1 then do;
    declare hash mx();
    rc = mx.defineKey(%list_quote_comma(&grp));
    rc = mx.definedata(%list_quote_comma(&max_val));
    rc = mx.definedone();
end;

rc = mx.find();
/*No Max for this combination -- add it*/
if rc then do;
    do i=1 to &n_val; /* %list_length(&val) */
        max[i] = val[i];
    end;
end;

/*Update Max Values*/
do i=1 to &n_val;
    if val[i] > max[i] then
        max[i] = val[i];
end;

/*Update Hash*/
rc = mx.replace();

drop rc i;
run;

%mend;


*---------------------------------------------------------------;
* LIST_LENGTH                                                   ;
* Length of space separated list                                ;
*---------------------------------------------------------------;
/* EXAMPLES :                                                    
   %put %list_length(item1 item2 item3);                                            
*/
%macro list_length
(data
);
%sysfunc(countw(&data,%str( )))
%mend;

*---------------------------------------------------------------;
* LIST_QUOTE_COMMA                                              ;
* create comma separated list with quoted items, from           ;
* unquoted space separated list.                                ;
*---------------------------------------------------------------;
/* EXAMPLE
%put %list_quote_comma(a b c);
*/
%macro list_quote_comma
(data /* space separated list to quote */
);
%unquote(%str(%')%qsysfunc(tranwrd(&data,%str( ),%str(%',%')))%str(%'))
%mend;

*---------------------------------------------------------------;
* LIST_FIX                                                      ;
* Add prefix and/or suffix to items of space separated list     ;
*---------------------------------------------------------------;
/* EXAMPLES :                                                    
   %put %list_fix(item1 item2 item3,pref_,_suf);                 
   %put %list_fix(item1 item2 item3,pref_);                 
   %put %list_fix(item1 item2 item3,suffix=_suf);                                           
*/

%macro list_fix
(data
,prefix
,suffix
);
%local output;
%do i=1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&data,%str( ))) ;
  %let output= &output &prefix.%scan(&data,&i,%str( ))&suffix;
%end;
&output
%mend;
```