# Using quotes in macro variables used in defineKey

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I'm trying to build a macro around the solution to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48648946/cumulative-max-by-group-in-sas-or-proc-sql/48649948#48649948)

My reproducible example here doesn't do anything useful, it's just to highlight the syntax error I'm getting.

The line `rc = mx.defineKey(&groups)` works in the first case, executing `rc = mx.defineKey('grp1','grp2')`.

In the second case however, where I define `&groups` differently but aiming at the same value, it fails with error:

> NOTE: Line generated by the macro variable "GROUPS". 21
>   'grp1','grp2'
>              _
>              386
>               _
>               200
>               76 MPRINT(TEST2):   rc = mx.defineKey('grp1','grp2'); ERROR: DATA STEP Component Object failure.  Aborted during the
>   COMPILATION phase. ERROR 386-185: Expecting an arithmetic expression.
>
> ERROR 200-322: The symbol is not recognized and will be ignored.
>
> ERROR 76-322: Syntax error, statement will be ignored.

Here are the working example followed by the non working one. I would like to:

- Understand why second case is not working
- Get it to work by defining `groups` from `grp_list` the appropriate way.

**Reproducible code:**

```
data have;
input grp1 $ grp2 $ number;
datalines;
a c 3
b d 4
;

%macro test;
data want;
set have;
if _n_ = 1 then do;
    declare hash mx();
    %let groups = 'grp1','grp2';
    %put rc = mx.defineKey(&groups);
    %put rc = mx.defineKey('grp1','grp2');
    rc = mx.defineKey(&groups);
    rc = mx.definedata('number');
    rc = mx.definedone();
end;
run;
%mend;

%test

%macro test2;
data want;
set have;
if _n_ = 1 then do;
    declare hash mx();
    %let grp_list = grp1 grp2;
    %let groups = %str(%')%qsysfunc(tranwrd(&grp_list,%str( ),%str(%',%')))%str(%');
    %put rc = mx.defineKey(&groups);
    %put rc = mx.defineKey('grp1','grp2');
    rc = mx.defineKey(&groups);
    rc = mx.definedata('number');
    rc = mx.definedone();
end;
run;
%mend;

%test2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the macro quoting as it is adding invisible control characters that are messing up your hash definition. Change the relevant line to this:

```
rc = mx.defineKey(%unquote(&groups));
```

You might also consider defining a separate macro to quote each of your list items, and using double quotes rather than single quotes, e.g.

```
%macro quotelist(list);
  %local i word;
  %do %while(1);
    %let i = %eval(&i + 1);
    %let word = %scan(&list,&i,%str( ));
    %if &word = %then %return;
%sysfunc(quote(&word)) /*De-indent to avoid adding extra spaces*/
  %end;
%mend;

%put %sysfunc(translate(%quotelist(a b c),%str(,),%str( )));
```

This avoids the additional hassles associated with resolving macro variables inside single quotes.

Comment: Actually executiong your example with `quotelist` I can't get rid of the extra space and thus your `%put` statement in the end displays commas by pairs

Comment: It came from the space at the end of `%if &word = %then %return; ` . I permitted myself to remove it

Answer (score 1):

Don't embed your macro logic into the middle of the DATA step. It might confuse you into thinking that it runs while the data step is running instead of running before the data step as it actually does.

Why are you jumping through hoops to add single quotes?  Just use double quotes.

```
%macro test2;
%let grp_list = grp1 grp2;
%let groups = "%sysfunc(tranwrd(&grp_list,%str( ),"%str(,)"))";
%put rc = mx.defineKey(&groups);
%put rc = mx.defineKey("grp1","grp2");
data want;
  set have;
  if _n_ = 1 then do;
    declare hash mx();
    rc = mx.defineKey(&groups);
    rc = mx.definedata("number");
    rc = mx.definedone();
  end;
run;
%mend test2;
```

Comment: I am a bit confused about your sentence anticipating my potential confusion :). Are you clarifying that the macros are replaced with text before anything is running, so that the data step is run after all the macros ?

Comment: The macro processor evaluates the input stream, processing any macro triggers like `&` and `%` and then the resulting text is passed to normal SAS to be run.  Since SAS compiles data steps a %LET statement that appears in the middle of a data step will have been evaluated BEFORE the data step starts running.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is due to macro quoting. It is fine when you print it to log via put. However, when you call it with defineKey methods. SAS parser sees additional quotations. That is way you get it failed at complication phase, before execution. (The symbol is not recognized - that is the macro quoting). If you remove the macro quoting, it will work.

```
%macro test2;
data want;
set have;
if _n_ = 1 then do;
    declare hash mx();
    %let grp_list = grp1 grp2;
    %let groups = %str(%')%qsysfunc(tranwrd(&grp_list,%str( ),%str(%',%')))%str(%');
    %put rc = mx.defineKey(&groups);
    %put rc = mx.defineKey('grp1','grp2');
    rc = mx.defineKey(%unquote(&groups));
    rc = mx.definedata('number');
    rc = mx.definedone();
end;
run;
%mend;
```